# Cast String into Date in BigQuery when Date is in the following format: DD-mon-YYYY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a string that is a date and it is in this format 'dd-mon-yy' ie:

27-Jan-18
28-Jan-18

How do I convert it into date with this format 'dd/mm/yyyy' using Standard SQL in BigQuery?

Comment: I have tried PARE_DATE, which throws error - Failed to parse input string "27-Jan-18".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert dates from the string format to a particular date format, you will first have to convert the string to a date using the [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date) function in BigQuery and then use the [FORMAT_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_date) function to convert the date into the desired format. Here is a snippet of code that converts the string of type "DD-Mon-YY" to a date value of the format dd/mm/yyyy:

SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%d/%m/%E4Y", PARSE_DATE("%d-%b-%y", "name_of_column_with_string_dates")) as formatted_dates FROM `projectId.dataset.table`